# Show only one record in Mult-Tenant auth System Laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

I’m building a mult-tenant auth system, that each user can belong of “x” companies.
In Users Table, there is a field named “companies_id”, that contain the companies IDS that he belongs ( between “,” ), ex: 1,9,25,30.
I can List all User Companies through query scopes e Query Builder:

```
class Company extends Model
{

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope());

}

class CompanyScope implements Scope
{

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {

$companies_id = auth()->user()->companies_id;
    $pieces = explode(",", $ companies _id);
    foreach ($pieces as $k){
        $builder->orwhere('companies_id', $k);
}
}
```

In INDEX page is OK, but, if I need show only ONE Company that a user belongs I can’t.
I Have a Method in Company Controller  :
Show($id){
}.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are working on a multi tenant app on a single shared database concept, it is not a good idea in the long run, I am just giving you my opinion, if you can separate the database for each company and make the database connection on the fly, it will give you more control in the future when your database grow,

and this article lists all the advantage of having separate database over shared database.
https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/139/laravel-database-per-user-on-the-fly-database-connections-multi-tenant-laravel-app-user-own-db

Comment: Dear Friend. First, Thanks for your reply. But for this project I need to develop with 1 database, but I read your article, very good.